# Different type of group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this code:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re

with open('cluster_whit_eefinder_c1.clstr','r') as cluster_file, open('cluster_whit_eefinder_c1.clstr.cd.clstr.tsv','w') as cluster_formated:
    cluster_file_reader = cluster_file.readlines()
    cluster_formated_writer = csv.writer(cluster_formated,delimiter='\t')
    cluster_formated_writer.writerow(['Sequence','Cluster','Representative'])
    cluster_list = []
    for line in cluster_file_reader:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if 'Cluster' in line:
            cluster_number = re.sub(r'>Cluster ','',line)
        else:
            if 'at ' in line:
                representative = 'FALSE'
            else:
                representative = 'TRUE'
            sequence_name = re.sub(r'.*>','',line)
            sequence_name = re.sub(r'\.\.\..*','',sequence_name)
            cluster_list.append([sequence_name,cluster_number,representative])
    cluster_formated_writer.writerows(cluster_list)
df = pd.read_csv('cluster_whit_eefinder_c1.clstr.cd.clstr.tsv',sep='\t')
df
```

[The result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1aXP.png)

And I want to group the rows in groups, with the row that is "representative" == True in the start and the others of the same "Cluster" in one cell like this (utilizing the "Cluster" 0):

| Representative | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| Aag2_family_100_all/002976F:64308-67798 | 001769F:313867-314004 002976F:64419-65996 002976F:66383-66751 002976F:66783-67274 |

I've tried to use `groupby` on pandas, but kind doesn't work for it, maybe cause it have to be `int` column.

Sorry, if the problem is not well explained, I have tried my best to give every detail and try to explain what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sample

```python
from random import randint as ri

seq_gen = lambda: '{:06d}F:{:06d}-{:06d}'.format(*(ri(0,999999) for _ in range(0,3)))
rows = 579
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sequence': ['Aag2_family_100_all/' + seq_gen()]
                +['Aag2_family_100_all/' + seq_gen() if ri(0,5)==1 else seq_gen() for _ in range(0,rows-1)],
})
df['Cluster'] = df.Sequence.str.contains('Aag').cumsum()-1
df['Representative'] = df.Sequence.str.contains('Aag')
print(df)
```

###### Output:

```
                                      Sequence  Cluster  Representative
0    Aag2_family_100_all/547059F:625094-139692        0            True
1                        523894F:467716-463528        0           False
2                        600021F:723574-943890        0           False
3    Aag2_family_100_all/603206F:464021-210040        1            True
4                        492211F:196425-898764        1           False
..                                         ...      ...             ...
574                      000882F:215662-933095       89           False
575                      614985F:580409-440631       89           False
576                      534945F:239988-734139       89           False
577  Aag2_family_100_all/774483F:035534-164305       90            True
578                      197869F:209375-491106       90           False

[579 rows x 3 columns]
```

### Solution

```python
concat = df.groupby(['Cluster','Representative']).transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)).drop_duplicates()
concat.columns = ['Representative']
concat['Sequence'] = concat.shift(-1)
concat['Sequence'][concat.Representative.str.contains('Aag') == concat['Sequence'].str.contains('Aag')] = ''
concat[concat.Representative.str.contains('Aag')]
```

###### Output:

```
    Representative                              Sequence
0   Aag2_family_100_all/547059F:625094-139692   523894F:467716-463528,600021F:723574-943890
3   Aag2_family_100_all/603206F:464021-210040   492211F:196425-898764,867928F:941840-843644,51...
10  Aag2_family_100_all/231092F:970858-588913   742156F:503328-047166,721999F:120276-150890,14...
19  Aag2_family_100_all/788580F:727948-571558   453161F:411712-464978
21  Aag2_family_100_all/929958F:726760-909563   
... ...                                         ...
554 Aag2_family_100_all/395708F:349121-530644   998001F:085268-773536
556 Aag2_family_100_all/745503F:998957-647906   959848F:625596-885757,218656F:940854-289334,34...
567 Aag2_family_100_all/176426F:399512-310563   275602F:454063-187206,290391F:837992-990191,85...
571 Aag2_family_100_all/481691F:863795-874835   212714F:404592-576988,891304F:080555-702858,00...
577 Aag2_family_100_all/774483F:035534-164305   197869F:209375-491106

[91 rows × 2 columns]
```

Comment: With your solution, non representative are getting into the representative column, and I dont know why :/

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/hJnrIKc)

Comment: @YagoDias looks like you did not save the last step to a variable before saving it to excel. `concat = concat[concat.Representative.str.contains('Aag')]`. I'm showing the output in [Jupiter](https://jupyter.org/), that means it outputs the last line of code.

Comment: Or `concat[concat.Representative.str.contains('Aag')].to_excel('my_beautiful_excel.xlsx')`

Comment: Sorry, @DiMithras, I misunderstood your answer, you were right